# protractor: what is the relationship between the control flow and javascript event loop?

Tags: protractor

I'm having a difficult time trying to understand how the control flow in protractor work in relation to how JS event loop works. Here is what I know so far:

Protractor control flow stores commands that return promises in a queue. The first command will be at the front of the queue and the last command will be at the back. No command will be executed until the command in front of it has its promise resolved.

JS event loop stores asynchronous task (callbacks to be specific). Callbacks are not executed until all functions in the stack have completed and the stack is empty. Before running each callback, there is a check on whether the stack is empty or not.

so lets take this code for example. The code is basically clicking a search button and a api request is made. Then after data is returned, it checks whether the field that stores the returned data exists.

```
elem('#searchButton').click(); //will execute a api call to retrieve data
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(elem('#resultDataField'),3000));
expect(elem('#resultDataField').isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

So with this code, I'm able to get it to work. But I don't know how it does it. How is the event loop applied in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The core of the ControlFlow implementation is in [`runEventLoop_`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/webdriver/promise.js#L1714) (in Selenium's promise.js implementation).

As I understand it, the ControlFlow registers a call to `runEventLoop_` with the JS event loop (e.g., with a 0-second timeout or somesuch).  The call to `runEventLoop_` can be thought of as a single iteration of a normal event loop.  It registers code to actually run a scheduled task (i.e., actually do the work you queued up during your `it`).  Once that task completes or fails (e.g., by hooking its async promise callbacks) the next iteration of `runEventLoop_` is scheduled (see the calls to `scheduleEventLoop` in `runEventLoop_`).

There is some complexity when a callback ends up registering new promises (those need to be "inserted" before the old next event, this is accomplished by creating a "nested" control flow.  Mostly you should never have to know this.)